# HTTP Request being blocked by Config Server Firewall react native

Tags: react-native, firewall

I have built a react native app for android. In the app it's making http requests to port 3000. The problem is that sometimes the config server firewall blocks the requests and the react native app is not working correctly. Has anyone had this issue before??

Comment: Please see [ask] and [help/on-topic]: for a question on programming issues, there are no steps to reproduce, and it looks like more about infrastructure/server setup/configuration.  Further, your only question here, "Has anyone had this issue before?", does not look like it'll provide you with a solution if answered. Please edit to be on topic, or find a stackexchange site where it is. I've removed the [tag:apache] tag, as there's no indication about its involvement/relevance in the question either